# DuplicateServiceException JBoss Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-10

I am getting a weird error when trying to run an EAR on my Wildfly 10 Server. It says `.session is already registered`, which other similar bugs have supposedly been caused by multiple applications using the same `context-root`. But I am just deploying a single EAR so I'm confused.

```
09:57:30,654 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."********.ear"."*********.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."***********.ear"."**********".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "******.war" of deployment "*******.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./******.session is already registered
```

Comment: This happened when you change the version number of your package and Wildfly tries to deploy two systems with the same context root. Remove the old package as suggested by @Devrim.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue. It is fixed by removing wars under:

```
<jboss or wildfly home>\standalone\deployments
```

directory.

**Edit:**
Another solution: Remove defined deployments at `<jboss or wildfly home>\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml`

Standalone.xml content, after deployments are removed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.2">
    ...
    <deployments></deployments>
</server>
```

Answer (score 3):

*Possible Fix*, previously I had had other errors with my files that I consequently fixed. I looked in my standalone directory and it contained a .failed EAR, and I believe the 'DuplicateServiceException' came from the server trying to deploy both of them. So recreating the server seemed to solve the problem. Hope that helps anyone with a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I deleted all the files in the server's deploy folder, cleaned the server and restart it. It works well after that.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me! I had this issue because I was going back and forth between the terminal and eclipse running my Jboss server.

Answer (score 0):

facing same issue clearing temp folder in home\standalone\tmp worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check your application.xml file it may be have duplicate context defined for multiple modules